# string after serialize is not inserted into the database

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have an `array`, I convert this `array to string` using `serialize` function. Then I tried to insert into the database. But this is not inserting into the database.

**What I tried is:**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_sample");
$text = array("PHP", "Java", "HTTML", "CSS");
$text = serialize($text);
//echo gettype($text); //gives type as string

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tbl_image(title) VALUES($text)");//not working

//mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tbl_image(title) VALUES(".$text.")");//not working

//mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tbl_image(title) VALUES('abc')"); //working 

mysqli_close($con);
```

**Table structure:**

table name: `tbl_image`

```
id    int   AutoIncrement
title text
```

How can I make this working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add quotes to sql query:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tbl_image(title) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $text)."')");
```

Comment: Also you can add a mysqli_real_escape_string function to preserve your DB from sql injection.

Comment: error:   Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: sorry, you need the connection in the first parameter.. `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $text)`, try now please